# EF6 Code First From Database. Edit template at propertyConfiguration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

I have installed the nuget package for my Entity Framework 6.x project that exposes the Code Templates. I am editing EntityType.cs.t4. I have identified the code I would like to change.

I would like to change [Required] (below) to [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=true)]

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
```

In the template this code appears to control that
            var propertyConfigurations = edm.GetConfigurations(property, Model).OfType();

```
    foreach (var propertyConfiguration in propertyConfigurations)
    {
#>
    <#= code.Attribute(propertyConfiguration) #>
<#
    }
```

How do I make the change?

Comment: are you using database-first?

Comment: Code first from database. EF6.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got it. Hope this helps someone else:

```
    var propertyConfigurations = edm.GetConfigurations(property, Model).OfType<IAttributeConfiguration>();

    foreach (var propertyConfiguration in propertyConfigurations)
    {
        if (code.Attribute(propertyConfiguration) == "[Required]")
        {
#>
    <#= "[Required(AllowEmptyStrings=true)]" #>
<#
        }
        else
        {
#>
    <#= code.Attribute(propertyConfiguration) #>
<#
        }
    }
#>
```

Here are my steps to debug:
a) copy in the code lines identified below
b) save the template
c) remove or comment out app.config connection string (so a new one can be created)
d) Delete the existing EntModel.cs file
e)Right click on the project and choose add new (data --> Entity framework --> Code First from Database) model.
d) The app will prompt you to open a new version of vs 2015 debugger and you can then debug.

---

This line exists at the very top

```
<#@ template visibility="internal" linePragmas="false" #>
```

Code Lines To Copy
1) Replace the line above with this line

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" hostspecific="true"#>
```

2) paste this in where you want to break

```
<#  
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();  
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); 
#>
```